# What happens to handlers when socket is deleted

Tags: c++, boost-asio

What happens to completion handlers when socket is shutdown/closed and then deleted (that is destructor is run and memory released)? AFAIK after socked it closed all completion handlers will receive error code next time even loop is polled. But what happens if the socked is deleted before even handlers had a chance to run? Is it OK to delete socket before dispatching event handlers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All handlers is guaranteed to be called. If socket was closed - handlers will be called with some error code.

Normally, you need to use this guarantee to control lifetime of your objects using boost::enable_shared_from_this.

```
class Writer : boost::enable_shared_from_this<Writer>
{  
  boost::asio::socket scoket_;

  ...

  void StartWrite() 
  {
      boost::asio::async_write(socket_,
          boost::asio::buffer(buffer_, bytes_sent_),
          boost::bind(&Writer::Handler, shared_from_this,
              boost::asio::placeholders::error));
  ...
  void Handler(boost::system::error_code const& err) {...}
```

With this approach, your socket object will outlive all pending handlers.

Comment: Could you clarify what do you mean by "guaranteed to be called"? What happens to completion handlers if I close and delete a socket and after that call io_service::poll? I my case it is OK if socket doesn't outlive its completion handlers.

Comment: All handlers will be canceled and dispatched to io_service with corresponding error code. When you call io_service::poll, all dispatched handlers will be called.

Comment: @pic11 if the socket doesn't outlive the handlers - it's ok. The problem is when the object bound to a handler doesn't outlive it.

Comment: @Igor R. It's not a problem, handlers will be called anywhere, with some other error code. Asio makes this guarantees to allow programmer to do any resource management in handlers.

Comment: @Igor R. Indeed! Completely agree with your previous comment. :)

Answer (score 2):

It is safe to delete a socket before its outstanding handlers have been executed.  Outstanding operations will have their handlers set to be invoked with `boost::asio::error::operation_aborted`.  It is the responsibility of the application code to to make sure that the handlers do not invoke operations on the deleted socket.

For details, [destroying](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_io_object/_basic_io_object.html) an IO object, such a socket, will cause the IO object's service to be destroyed.  The [`SocketService`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/SocketService.html) requirements state that `destroy()` will implicitly cancel asynchronous operations.  Outstanding asynchronous operations will try to complete as soon as possible.  This causes the handlers for cancelled operations to be  passed the error code `boost::asio::error::operation_aborted`, and scheduled for deferred invocation within the `io_service`.  These handlers are removed from the `io_service` if they are either invoked from a thread processing the event loop or the `io_service` is [destroyed](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/_io_service.html).